# Query not returning data while multiple values passing in "In" Clause using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

This is the my code:

```
declare @data nvarchar(max) = 'AA1,AA2,AA3'
set @data = replace(@data, ',', ''',''')
set @data = ' ''' + @data + ''' '

select @data

select * 
from tbl_Member 
where memberName in (@data)
```

I'm sending 'AA1,AA2,AA3' to `@data`,it returns 'AA1','AA2','AA3'

While using returned data in `IN` clause, I'm not getting data from table.

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand why you would think that would work, but the parser doesn't read your syntax as that literal. You should use table parameters here and you can avoid dynamic sql.

```
declare @data table(datas varchar(16))
insert into @data
values
('AA1'),
('AA2'),
('AA3')



declare @tbl_Member table (memberName varchar(64))
insert into @tbl_Member

values
('AA1'),
('AA2'),
('AA3'),
('AA4')

select * 
from @tbl_Member 
where memberName in (select * from @data)
```

Comment: Sure thing @QWTest

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
declare @data nvarchar(max) = 'AA1,AA2,AA3'
set @data = replace(@data, ',', ''',''')
set @data = ' ''' + @data + ''' '
DECLARE @query varchar(1024)
set @query = 'select * from tbl_Member where memberName in (' + @data + ')';
exec(@query)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
declare @data nvarchar(max) = 'AA1,AA2,AA3'
set @data = replace(@data, ',', ''',''')
set @data = ' ''' + @data + ''' '

select @data

EXEC('
select * 
from tbl_Member 
where memberName in ('+@data+')')
```